# Why does blink animation stop?

Tags: java, multithreading, animation

I have class that implements `SensorEventListener` and every time the method `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` is executed, a new RotateAnimation starts  (it is a compass).

In the method, I create an `AnimationListener()` for my rotate animation and in the listener, every time `onAnimationStart()` is called, I start a blinking animation.

Here I have two problems:

- The blinking animation executes every time the sensor changes, (this calls `onAnimationStart()` that then executes the blinking) so the blinking goes really fast.
- If I forced the blinking to be executed just once (by using a counter), I thought it would keep blinking since I set the animation as INFINITE but it stops.

I would like to know how can I maintain the blinking although the sensor thread starts again every time the sensor changes.

```
 @Override
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);

    rotate = new RotateAnimation(
            currentDegree, 
            -degree,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);

    rotate.setDuration(210);
    rotate.setFillAfter(true);

    compass.startAnimation(rotate);

    rotate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // Only enters one time so the blink starts
            // but then the blink stop when a new sensor thread is created
            if (count < 1){
               blink ();
               count++;  
            }
        }
    });
}

public void blink (){
    blink = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    blink.setDuration(400); // duration - half a second
    blink.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); 
    blink.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

    compass.startAnimation(blink);
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.  You want the blinking to start the first time `onSensorChanged` is invoked, and then to continue indefinitely even if more `onSensorChanged` events occur? When does the animation stop?  Also what does any of this have to do with the title?

Comment: Yes, I want exactly that. **The animation stops** when `onAnimationStart()`is called again (it does not enter in the `if()` ; if it enters, new blinks are created very time)

Comment: When do you decrement `count`?

Comment: `count` is a private int initiated to 0. It is done in propose so `blink()` is only called once and no every time `onAnimationStart ()` occurs